# Composition Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, analyticity

Is there any theorem that specifies when we are allowed to compose the taylor series of two functions? Does it have a name?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here's a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/323569/5531).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compostion of two analytic functions is analytic. The coefficients of the composed series can be calculated using [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)